# Dividing sum results

Tags: sql, sum, teradata, divide

I'm really sorry as this was probably answered before, but I couldn't find something that solved the problem.

In this case, I'm trying to get the result of dividing two sums in the same column.

```
| Id | month | budget | sales |
| -- | ----- | ------ | ----- |
| 1  | jan   | 1000   | 800   |
| 2  | jan   | 1000   | 850   |
| 1  | feb   | 1200   | 800   |
| 2  | feb   | 1100   | 850   |
```

What i want is to get the % of completition for each id and month (example: get 0,8 or 80% in a fifth column for id 1 in jan)
I have something like

```
sel 
id,
month,
sum (daily_budget) as budget,
sum (daily_sales) as sales,
budget/sales over (partition by 1,2) as efectivenes
from sales
group by 1,2
```

I know im doing this wrong but I'm kinda new with sql and cant find the way :|
Thanks!

Comment: Let me see if I understand.... you want your db table to contain a computed value column of sales/budget. Is that correct?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: You cannot use alias names defined in the select clause in the very same select clause. Are you merely looking for `sum (daily_budget) / sum (daily_sales) as efectivenes`? Otherwise please show the expected result.

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? You should always tag the DBMS when asking SQL questions. In most DBMS 1 / 2 = 0.5, but in SQL Server and some others it's 1 / 2 = 0 for instance. So always tag the DBMS.

Comment: Do you even need aggregation (`SUM` and `GROUP BY`)? From your sample data it looks like you merely want `select id, month, daily_budget, daily_sales, daily_budget / daily_sales as efectivenes from sales order by id, month`.

Comment: Hi, sorry, kinda new with this, im using Teradata SQL assistant, kinda dont really know what specific language it uses  :|

Comment: I needed the sum because this is just an example, but lets say that my db contains each sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```sql
CAST(ROUND(SUM(daily_sales) * 100.00 / SUM(daily_budget), 1) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS Effectiveness
```

Comment: And because Teradata allows reusing aliases this can be simplified to `100.00*budget/sales AS Effectiveness`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at SQL too but maybe I can help. Try this?

```
sel 
id,
month,
sum (daily_budget) as budget,
sum (daily_sales) as sales,
(sum(daily_budget)/sum(daily_sales)) over (partition by id) as efectivenes
from sales
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ALTER your table so that it contains a fifth column where the result of `budget/sales` is automatically calculated, all you need to do this add the formula to this auto-generated column. The example I am about to show is based on MySQL.

1. Open MySQL
2. Find the table you wish to modify in the Navigator Pane, right-click on it and select "Alter Table"

[image]

3. Add a new row to your table. Make sure you select NN (Not Null) and G (Generated Column) check boxes
4. In the Default/Expression column, simply enter the expression `budget / sales`.

[image]

Once you run your next query, you should see your column generated and populated with the calculated results. If you simply want the SQL statement to do the same from the console, it will be something like this:  `ALTER table YOUR_TABLE_NAME add result FLOAT as (budget / sales);`